# Gesture Recognizer on UIView in Table View Cell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

In my Table View, each cell contains a UIView which is smaller than the cell. I want to perform a segue to a Detail View only when the user tap on this UIView and not if he pressed the cell outside of the UIView. I tried to add a gesture recognizer to the UIView but when the associated method is called, it doesn't know which cell was pressed. What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign tag property (integer) to each view in unique way. For example, it can be integer number being combination of section and row.
Or some unique ID of objects for the cell from table data source.

Then in recognizer you can analize tag value.

Answer (score 0):

Create a delegate protocol (and a delegate property to match) in your cell subclass that has some method like 'cellWasSelected:(MYCell *)cell'. When you return your cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath:, set the ViewController as the delegate of the cell. Within the cell subclass, add whatever mechanism you want to determine when it was tapped. A gesture is fine. Call your delegates method passing self as the argument. In your ViewController, you can call tableview indexOfCell (or something like that, can't remember the name off the top of my head) to get the index path of you need it. Then, manually perform your segue. You can either store a 'selected cell' or even manually select that cell using the tableView which should trigger your segue if that is already set up.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a delegate to your CELL. What you can do, you know, you can get the reference of your `UIView` in your custom cell, like so:

```
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIView *tappableView;
```

and add gesture recognizers to it.

Now, create a protocol and create a method,

```
-(void)didTapViewAtCell:(MyCustomCell*)cell
```

Have a `delegate` that adheres to this protocol and call it in the target method of your gesture recognizer. Something like...

```
[self.delegate didTapViewAtCell:self];
```

Implement this protocol in your `UITableViewController` and implement this method. I think this is the best way to go on about it. :)

Comment: Thx for your response, but I am not very familiar with protocols, can you explain a bit more how to create a protocol please, and what do you mean by "have a delegate that adheres to this protocol" ? Thanks

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html
Read this first. :)

Comment: Ok, I read it but I'm not sure to understand very well, I still don't understand how to create a protocol and to have a delegate that adheres to it...

Comment: Ok, I understood, but there is a problem : in the line [self.delegate didTapViewAtCell:self];, the last self is of type ViewController and the method expect an object of type MyCustomCell. And I have the same problem : how can the target method of the gesture recognizer know which cell was selected ?

Comment: You should do `[self.delegate didTapViewAtCell:self]` at the `MyCustomCell` class. What you are doing is, you making the cell say, "Hey, I can't do this work, why don't you do it?"